# CoordinatorLayout showing error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using `CoordinatorLayout` layout in my app but it's showing error in inflating class `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` in Eclipse.

Please tell me how to remove this error.

My target API level is 21 and min SDK 18.

Here's my XML and list of libraries I have imported.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.support.android.designlibdemo"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="NestedScrollView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Info"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Friends"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Related"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

here's my logcat

```
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268): Process: com.support.android.designlibdemo, PID: 9268
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.support.android.designlibdemo/com.support.android.designlibdemo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at com.support.android.designlibdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     ... 10 more
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.support.android.designlibdemo-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     ... 21 more
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):         ... 24 more
11-06 14:17:37.473: E/AndroidRuntime(9268):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: I think its not supported with 21 try changing to 22 and add 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' in your gradle

Comment: @Nisarg i have changed it to 22 and i using eclipse so there is no gradle file but still not working,

Comment: did u import cardview,recyclerview,palette libraries?